# What kind of Ad that appears in the middle of screen

Tags: android

I need to know Type of Ad shown in the picture, thanks

[image: Ad layout highlighted]

Comment: ? https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: Use native ad https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can use Native Ad format. Firstly, include native ad library in your app. And then you should redesing layout like this.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

  <com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
        android:id="@+id/my_template"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:gnt_template_type="@layout/your_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```